# Applying a criterion on deficient numbers to the proper factors of an odd perfect number

Tags: number-theory, upper-lower-bounds, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

Hereinafter, let $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$ denote the *abundancy index* of the positive integer $x$, where $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$ is the *classical sum of divisors* of $x$.  Denote the *deficiency* of $x$ by
$$D(x)=2x-\sigma(x).$$

Call a positive integer $y$ *deficient* when $I(y) < 2$.  (Equivalently, $y$ is deficient when $D(y) \geq 1$.)

In this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.6767v7.pdf), the following result is proved:

> If $M > 1$ is deficient, then
> $$\frac{2M}{M + D(M)} < I(M) < \frac{2M + D(M)}{M + D(M)}.$$

Now, let $N = p^k m^2$ be an [odd perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) given in Eulerian form (i.e. $p$ is the special/Euler prime satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$).

Since $N$ is perfect, and $p^k$ and $m^2$ are proper factors of $N$, then $p^k$ and $m^2$ are deficient.  It follows that
$$\frac{2p^k}{p^k + D(p^k)} < I(p^k) < \frac{2p^k + D(p^k)}{p^k + D(p^k)}$$
and
$$\frac{2m^2}{m^2 + D(m^2)} < I(m^2) < \frac{2m^2 + D(m^2)}{m^2 + D(m^2)}.$$

Here is my:

> **QUESTION:** Does the following inequality hold in general, if $p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number with special/Euler prime $p$?
> $$\frac{2p^k + D(p^k)}{p^k + D(p^k)} \leq \frac{2m^2}{m^2 + D(m^2)}$$

**MY ATTEMPT**

Suppose to the contrary that
$$\frac{2m^2}{m^2 + D(m^2)} < \frac{2p^k + D(p^k)}{p^k + D(p^k)}.$$
This holds if and only if
$$\frac{2}{3 - I(m^2)} = \dfrac{\dfrac{2m^2}{m^2}}{\dfrac{m^2 + D(m^2)}{m^2}} < \dfrac{\dfrac{2p^k + D(p^k)}{p^k}}{\dfrac{p^k + D(p^k)}{p^k}} = \frac{4 - I(p^k)}{3 - I(p^k)}.$$
Since $p^k$ and $m^2$ are deficient, we may cross-multiply, giving
$$\frac{2}{3 - I(m^2)} < \frac{4 - I(p^k)}{3 - I(p^k)} \iff 2(3 - I(p^k)) < (4 - I(p^k))(3 - I(m^2))$$
$$\iff 6 - 2I(p^k) < 12 - 3I(p^k) - 4I(m^2) + I(p^k)I(m^2) = 14 - 3I(p^k) - 4I(m^2)$$
$$\iff 4I(m^2) + I(p^k) < 8.$$

Now, we use the fact that $p$ is the special prime (satisfying $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$) to derive a lower bound for $p$ (and therefore, an upper bound for $I(p^k)$):
$$p \text{ is prime and } p \equiv 1 \pmod 4 \implies p \geq 5$$
$$I(p^k) = \frac{\sigma(p^k)}{p^k} = \frac{p^{k+1} - 1}{p^k (p - 1)} < \frac{p^{k+1}}{p^k (p - 1)} = \frac{p}{p - 1} \leq \frac{5}{4}.$$

Hence the inequality
$$4I(m^2) + I(p^k) < 8$$
together with the inequality
$$3I(p^k) < \frac{15}{4}$$
implies that
$$4(I(p^k) + I(m^2)) < 8 + \frac{15}{4} = \frac{47}{4}$$
from which we obtain
$$I(p^k) + I(m^2) < \frac{47}{16},$$
which is better than the currently known $I(p^k) + I(m^2) < 3$.

But it is known that
$$3 - \bigg(\frac{p-2}{p(p-1)}\bigg) < I(p^k) + I(m^2).$$

Together with
$$I(p^k) + I(m^2) < \frac{47}{16}$$
this gives
$$3 - \bigg(\frac{p-2}{p(p-1)}\bigg) < \frac{47}{16}$$
$$\iff \frac{1}{16} < \frac{p-2}{p(p-1)}$$
$$\iff p(p - 1) < 16(p - 2)$$
$$\iff p^2 - 17p + 32 < 0$$
$$\iff \frac{17 - \sqrt{161}}{2} < p < \frac{17 + \sqrt{161}}{2}.$$

The lower bound thus obtained for $p$:
$$p > \frac{17 - \sqrt{161}}{2} \approx 2.15571$$
is trivial, and may be replaced by the lower bound $p \geq 5$.

The upper bound thus obtained for $p$:
$$p < \frac{17 + \sqrt{161}}{2} \approx 14.8443$$
is *nontrivial*.

Note that we then have either
$$p \in \{5, 13\}.$$

If $p = 5$, then
$$\frac{57}{20} < I(5^k) + I(m^2) = I(5^k) + \frac{2}{I(5^k)} = \frac{5^{k+1} - 1}{5^k (5 - 1)} + \frac{2 \bigg({5^k} (5 - 1)\bigg)}{5^{k+1} - 1} = \frac{57 \times 5^{2k} - 2 \times 5^{k+1} + 1}{4\times {5^k} (5^{k+1} - 1)} < \frac{47}{16}.$$

[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%2057%2F20%20%3C%20%28%285%5E%28k%2B1%29%20-%201%29%2F%285%5Ek%20%284%29%29%29%20%2B%20%282%2F%28%285%5E%28k%2B1%29%20-%201%29%2F%285%5Ek%20%284%29%29%29%29%20%3C%2047%2F16%20for%20k) gives the solution
$$k > \dfrac{\log\bigg(\dfrac{7 + \sqrt{161}}{14}\bigg)}{\log(5)} \approx 0.211864,$$
which is trivial.

If $p = 13$, then
$$\frac{57}{20} < I({13}^k) + I(m^2) = I({13}^k) + \frac{2}{I({13}^k)} = \frac{{13}^{k+1} - 1}{{13}^k (13 - 1)} + \frac{2 \bigg({{13}^k} (13 - 1)\bigg)}{{13}^{k+1} - 1} = \frac{457 \times {13}^{2k} - 2 \times {13}^{k+1} + 1}{{12}\times {{13}^k} ({13}^{k+1} - 1)} < \frac{47}{16}.$$

[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%2057%2F20%20%3C%20%28%28%2813%29%5E%28k%2B1%29%20-%201%29%2F%28%2813%29%5Ek%20%2812%29%29%29%20%2B%20%282%2F%28%28%2813%29%5E%28k%2B1%29%20-%201%29%2F%28%2813%29%5Ek%20%2812%29%29%29%29%20%3C%2047%2F16%20for%20k) gives the solution
$$k > \dfrac{\log\bigg(\dfrac{37 + 3\sqrt{161}}{10}\bigg)}{\log(13)} \approx 0.785894,$$
which is trivial.

**Alas, this is where I get stuck.**

**References:**

*A criterion for deficient numbers using the abundancy index and deficiency functions*, Journal for Algebra and Number Theory Academia, Volume 8, Issue 1, February 2018, pp 1 to 9, preprint available [online](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.6767v7.pdf)

*The abundancy index of divisors of odd perfect numbers - Part III*, Notes on Number Theory and Discrete Mathematics, Volume 23, Number 3, October 2017, pp 53 to 59, available [online](http://nntdm.net/volume-23-2017/number-3/53-59/)

Comment: I am hoping someone could also rule out $p=5$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality
$$\frac{2p^k + D(p^k)}{p^k + D(p^k)} \leq \frac{2m^2}{m^2 + D(m^2)}$$
holds if and only if $$p\ge 13$$

*Proof* :

We see that
$$\frac{2p^k + D(p^k)}{p^k + D(p^k)} \leq \frac{2m^2}{m^2 + D(m^2)}\tag1$$
is equivalent to
$$ (p-8)p^{2k+1}+8p^{2k}+2p^k(3p-4)+1\ge 0\tag2$$
because
$$\begin{align}(1)&\iff 2m^2(p^k+D(p^k))-(2p^k+D(p^k))(m^2+D(m^2))\ge 0
\\\\&\iff 2m^2p^k+2m^2(2p^k-\sigma(p^k))-2p^km^2-2p^k(2m^2-\sigma(m^2))
\\&\qquad \qquad -m^2(2p^k-\sigma(p^k))-(2p^k-\sigma(p^k))(2m^2-\sigma(m^2))\ge 0
\\\\&\iff 4p^k\sigma(m^2)+m^2\sigma(p^k)-8p^km^2\ge 0
\\\\&\iff 4p^k\frac{2p^km^2}{\sigma(p^k)}+m^2\sigma(p^k)-8p^km^2\ge 0
\\\\&\iff 8p^{2k}+\sigma(p^k)^2-8p^k\sigma(p^k)\ge 0
\\\\&\iff 8p^{2k}+\bigg(\frac{p^{k+1}-1}{p-1}\bigg)^2-8p^k\frac{p^{k+1}-1}{p-1}\ge 0
\\\\&\iff 8p^{2k}(p-1)^2+(p^{k+1}-1)^2-8p^k(p^{k+1}-1)(p-1)\ge 0
\\\\&\iff (p-8)p^{2k+1}+8p^{2k}+2p^k(3p-4)+1\ge 0\end{align}$$

Now,

- If $p\ge 13$, then we see that $(2)$ holds.
- If $p\lt 13$, i.e. $p=5$, then $(2)$ is equivalent to $5^k(7\cdot 5^{k}-22)\le 1$ which is impossible.

In conclusion, we have
$$\frac{2p^k + D(p^k)}{p^k + D(p^k)} \leq \frac{2m^2}{m^2 + D(m^2)}\iff p\ge 13$$

Answer (score 1):

I guess the case $p=13$ can be eliminated.
We obtain $I(13^k) < \frac {13}{12}$, which implies $I(p^k) + I(m^2) < \frac{45}{16}$. But now we have
$$3-\frac{p-2}{p(p-1)} = 3 - \left( \frac{11}{13 \cdot 12} \right ) = \frac{457}{156} > \frac{45}{16} > I(m^2)+I(p^k),$$
contrary to the result you stated.

Comment: Splendid!  I hope you do not mind my minor typographical edit on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

We want to show that
$$\frac{2p^k + D(p^k)}{p^k + D(p^k)} \leq \frac{2m^2}{m^2 + D(m^2)}.$$
As in the **OP**, assume to the contrary that
$$\frac{2m^2}{m^2 + D(m^2)} < \frac{2p^k + D(p^k)}{p^k + D(p^k)}.$$
As shown in the **OP**, this is equivalent to
$$4I(m^2) + I(p^k) < 8,$$
which is equivalent to
$$I(m^2) + \frac{I(p^k)}{4} < 2.$$
But the **LHS** is bounded from below by
$$I(m^2) > \frac{2(p-1)}{p}$$
and
$$\frac{I(p^k)}{4} \geq \frac{p+1}{4p}$$
so that we have
$$\frac{2(p-1)}{p} + \frac{p+1}{4p} < I(m^2) + \frac{I(p^k)}{4} < 2,$$
which is equivalent to
$$2 - \frac{2}{p} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4p} < 2 \iff \frac{1}{4} < \frac{7}{4p} \iff p < 7 \implies p = 5,$$
confirming [LurchiDerLurch](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/744506)'s findings.